# Poor quality while using PC Output Playback as Microphone for Android Phone

Tags: audio-recording

I plugged a mic/headphone Y spliter on my smartphone.

My PC sends sound output to my Android phone (Huawei) from a 3.5mm jack plugged to the mic connector of  the spliter mentioned above, which itself is connected to my android phone.

I played a music on my PC and started a record application on my smartphone.

When I play & listen the recorded song on my Android device the song is crackling too much, with a very poor quality. 
I did the same thing on another application (WhatsApp) and the quality is a bit better.

If I use a digital voice recorder instead it works very well.

I don't get it, how can I manage to make it works on my android device ? I have read somewhere on this site that I need to build an "attenuator" but in my case it's not working only on some apps. Can someone explain what's happening technically ?

Comment: When you say it's crackling, is the sound very loud?

Comment: That's the worst possible method of transferring music from your PC to your phone, by the way. You should transfer the music file instead.

Answer (score 1):

The signal from your PC is too high voltage, hence it distorts. This is not the way to transfer music from PC to phone - in fact as @Hobbes pointed out, it is the worst possible way to do it.

If you want to move music from your PC to your android phone, use a USB connection and file manager and simply drag and drop the file across.

The digital recorder knows what volume to expect in the mic (and adjusts gain accordingly) so that you don't distort - you do however lose quality in terms of the relative amplitude of different frequencies, depending on the mic profile.